Flutter: Saved Audio Not Accessible in Music Player Apps
I'm developing a Flutter app that generates MP3 audio files.
I can successfully save these files to the device storage. However, they're not showing up in any music player apps.
I'm using the path_provider package to get a suitable directory for saving the audio files.
How can I make the saved MP3 files discoverable by music player apps?

The sample rate of your files is?

What do you mean by rate? If you mean frequency, their value is 48000, 44100, or 22050. @pierpy

Yes, sample rate = frequency. Can you share a file, or a short part of it? I can deep analyze audio files , I'm a sound engineer. If you don't see them in any player, that's because they are in a non standard format, or there's another problem that's not strictly related to audio

Can u introduce a source for audio standards? https://file.io/frQnS05qTJZi @pierpy


I don't see any technical issues in your file 2) There is  a problem in the average level, max peak is at -36dBFS, and the average level is at -53. The end user won't be able to hear it. 3) To know about audio formats, start on Wikipedia; there are no "official"  sources


I can reproduce your file on any player I have. Maybe you have to investigate for read permissions on source folder
